# Python Updating Variables Based on Current Widget Selected

Tags: python, matplotlib, qwidget

There are a few examples out there of how to do this, but after trying all of them I don't understand how to correctly implement it. I have a program that a button creates a widget with contents inside and assigns it to a grid layout, and it also creates a figure on a canvas. Clicking on the button again creates another widget filled with the same contents and another figure and assigns it to the layout.

One of the contents is a spin box which controls the rotation of the figure. I want each spin box to be able to control the figure that was created with it individually. Here is where I am stuck.

How do I have a general button that can create several widgets, but then on every value change of each spin box, be able to tell which widget it came from so it will rotate the correct figure? I want the widget id or name or however I can access it. Here is what I have so far - Thanks in advance!:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas, NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np 
import math
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
from mplwindow5 import Ui_mplMainWindow
from cU_widget import cU_Widget

class Viewer(QMainWindow, Ui_mplMainWindow):  
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Viewer, self).__init__(parent) 
        self.setupUi(self)      
        self.count = 0          
        self.cU_widget = []
        self.cU_rotate = []
        self.lbl_cU_rotate = []
        self.lbl_cU = []

        self.btn_cU.clicked.connect(self.add_cU) 

    def add_cU(self):
        self.cU_widget.append(int(self.count))

        self.cU_widget[self.count] = QWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.cU_widget[self.count].setMinimumSize(QSize(101, 81))
        self.cU_widget[self.count].setMaximumSize(QSize(101, 81))
        self.cU_widget[self.count].setObjectName("cU_widget"  + str(self.count+1))

        self.lbl_cU.append(int(self.count))

        self.lbl_cU[self.count] = QLabel("cU " + str(self.count+1), self.cU_widget[self.count])
        self.lbl_cU[self.count].setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 101, 27))
        self.lbl_cU[self.count].setObjectName("lbl_cU_" + str(self.count+1))

        self.lbl_cU_rotate.append(int(self.count))

        self.lbl_cU_rotate[self.count] = QLabel("R", self.cU_widget[self.count])
        self.lbl_cU_rotate[self.count].setGeometry(QRect(6, 50, 20, 20))
        self.lbl_cU_rotate[self.count].setObjectName("lbl_cU_rotate"  + str(self.count+1))

        self.cU_rotate.append(int(self.count))

        self.cU_rotate[self.count] = QDoubleSpinBox(self.cU_widget[self.count])
        self.cU_rotate[self.count].setGeometry(QRect(20, 40, 71, 27))
        self.cU_rotate[self.count].setObjectName("cU_rotate"  + str(self.count+1))

        self.cU_rotate[self.count].valueChanged.connect(self.cU) # ??? What to use here

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.cU_widget[self.count], self.count, 0)

        self.cU()

    def cU(self):

        self.cU_rotate[self.count] = self.cU_rotate[self.count].value()  # ?? What to use here

        rotate = 1          
        tt = np.arange(0,1, 0.001)  

        lco_x0 = 0
        lco_x1 = 4

        lco_y0 = 1
        lco_y1 = 3

        cU_L_x0 = (lco_x0 * math.cos(math.radians(self.cU_rotate[self.count] + rotate))) - (lco_y0 * math.sin(math.radians(self.cU_rotate[self.count] + rotate)))
        cU_L_x1 = (lco_x1 * math.cos(math.radians(self.cU_rotate[self.count] + rotate))) - (lco_y1 * math.sin(math.radians(self.cU_rotate[self.count] + rotate)))
        #...   
        cU_L_y0 = (lco_x0 * math.sin(math.radians(self.cU_rotate[self.count] + rotate))) + (lco_y0 * math.cos(math.radians(self.cU_rotate[self.count] + rotate)))
        cU_L_y1 = (lco_x1 * math.sin(math.radians(self.cU_rotate[self.count] + rotate))) + (lco_y1 * math.cos(math.radians(self.cU_rotate[self.count] + rotate)))
        #...    
        cU_L_ax = ( 1  * cU_L_x0) 
        cU_L_bx = ((-6  * cU_L_x0) +(30 * cU_L_x1))
        # ...    
        cU_L_ay = ( 1  * cU_L_y0)
        cU_L_by = ((-6  * cU_L_y0) +(30 * cU_L_y1))
        #...    
        cU_L_xtt = (cU_L_ax * tt**2) + (cU_L_bx * tt) + 1
        cU_L_ytt = (cU_L_ay * tt**2) + (cU_L_by * tt) + 1

        self.mplContainer.canvas.ax.plot(cU_L_xtt, cU_L_ytt, 'r')

        self.mplContainer.canvas.ax.set_ylim([-5, 5])
        self.mplContainer.canvas.ax.set_xlim([0, 10])
        self.mplContainer.canvas.ax.set_aspect(1)

        self.mplContainer.canvas.draw()

        self.count += 1

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
viewer = Viewer()
viewer.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

here is mplwindow5:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_mplMainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, mplMainWindow):
        mplMainWindow.setObjectName("mplMainWindow")
        mplMainWindow.resize(1171, 826)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(mplMainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.mplContainer = MplWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.mplContainer.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(259, 20, 861, 741))
        self.mplContainer.setObjectName("mplContainer")
        self.inputContainer = QtGui.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.inputContainer.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 251, 741))
        self.inputContainer.setObjectName("inputContainer")

        self.scrollArea = QtGui.QScrollArea(self.inputContainer)
        self.scrollArea.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 160, 241, 581))
        self.scrollArea.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.WinPanel)
        self.scrollArea.setLineWidth(1)
        self.scrollArea.setMidLineWidth(10)
        self.scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 226, 577))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")

        self.scrollLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)

        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.gridLayout.setColumnStretch(0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setColumnStretch(2, 4)

        self.scrollLayout.addLayout(self.gridLayout)
        self.scrollLayout.addStretch()

        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        mplMainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.btn_cU = QtGui.QPushButton("cU", self.inputContainer)
        self.btn_cU.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 31, 27))
        self.btn_cU.setObjectName("btn_cU")  

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(mplMainWindow)



from mplwidget import MplWidget
```

mplwidget:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas, NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar 
from matplotlib.figure import Figure 

class MplCanvas(FigureCanvas):    
    def __init__(self):    
        self.fig = Figure()
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)     
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)   
        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

class MplWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):  
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)   
        self.main_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.canvas = MplCanvas()
        self.ntb = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self.main_widget)

        self.vbl = QGridLayout()
        self.vbl.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.vbl.addWidget(self.ntb)

        self.setLayout(self.vbl)
```

Comment: Can you make this example a [mcve]?  E.g. the button click would not need to perform 40 lines of code to show the problem, right?

Comment: Sorry, still not minimal. There are a lot of undefined variables. Also I don't have `mplwindow4` to import from.

Comment: Now it seems to work partially. What is the scrollbox for? Should there be any items in it? Apart, I don't understand the problem, but maybe someone else will.

Comment: The scroll box is used for 2 things: the scroll box contains a grid layout and stretch. the cU button places the widgets onto a grid inside the scroll box. There could be tens of these widgets so if there is more, i may need to scroll down to access them. Also there is a stretch added to the scroll so that it keeps the widgets close together when they are added instead of trying to fill the whole grid space.

Comment: The program normally contains a set of 6th degree curves that are plotted. The goal is to be able to create as many of these curves as I need via the cU button, and be able to manipulate and rotate each one of these on the canvas individually through its own widget(Here is the problem, how to access the current widget selected If i change the spin box value, i want the connected curve to be able to rotate according to that value.)  The red line you see is just a "placeholder" as a 6th degree polynomial is alot of code and I had to shorten it down extensively.

Comment: From my solution below you see that a  [mcve] can be much more minimal than what you provide here and that you don't need to use the same (possibly very complicated) problem you are trying to solve to ask a question about an issue you encounter. Instead, try to find the most simple problem that, if solved, would allow you to solve your problem. It took me a lot of time to actually understand that your problem is the updating of the curves, as this part is very much hidden in the code you show in the question.

Comment: I would also like to ask you to check all of your older questions and see if the answers provided actually solve the respective issue. If this is the case you should consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) them. You may also consider upvoting if they helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's not necessary to make extensive mathematical manipulations to solve this issue, I ignored that part. So let's assume that we want to change the slope of several lines using SpinBoxes.

An option would be to make the lines be part of a class that controls the SpinBoxes as well as the matplotlib lines. I called it `LineWidget` in the code below. When the button is pressed a new `LineWidget` instance is created and added to a scroll area, where you can manipulate the parameter. Once the parameter changes the line is updated.

Here is a full example where I also simplified the rest of the code.

```
import sys
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np 
from PyQt4 import QtGui , QtCore

class Viewer(QtGui.QMainWindow):  
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Viewer, self).__init__(parent) 
        self.setupUI() 
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.count = 0          
        self.container = []
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.addLine) 

    def setupUI(self):
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.centralwidget.setLayout(QtGui.QHBoxLayout())

        self.leftWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.leftWidget.setMinimumWidth(200)
        self.leftWidget.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())

        self.mplWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.mplWidget.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())

        self.fig = Figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
        self.ntb = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self.mplWidget)
        self.mplWidget.layout().addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.mplWidget.layout().addWidget(self.ntb)

        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("Push")

        self.scrollWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.scrollLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.scrollWidget.setLayout(self.scrollLayout)
        self.scrollLayout.addStretch()
        self.scrollArea = QtGui.QScrollArea()
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollWidget)

        self.leftWidget.layout().addWidget(self.button)
        self.leftWidget.layout().addWidget(self.scrollArea)

        self.centralwidget.layout().addWidget(self.leftWidget)
        self.centralwidget.layout().addWidget(self.mplWidget)

    def addLine(self):
        b = LineWidget(self.count, self.ax)
        self.container.append(b)
        self.scrollLayout.insertWidget(self.scrollLayout.count() - 1, b)
        self.count += 1


class LineWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__( self, number, ax, R=0, parent=None, **kwargs):
        super(LineWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.number = number
        label = QtGui.QLabel("cU " + str(self.number))
        self.spin = QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.spin.setSingleStep(0.2)
        self.spin.setRange(-100,100)
        self.setLayout(QtGui.QHBoxLayout())
        self.layout().addWidget(label)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.spin)

        self.R = R
        self.t = np.linspace(0,1)
        self.f = lambda t, R: R*t
        self.ax = ax
        self.line, = self.ax.plot([],[], **kwargs)

        self.update()
        self.spin.valueChanged.connect(self.changed)

    def changed(self):
        self.R = self.spin.value()
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        self.line.set_data(self.t, self.f(self.t, self.R))
        self.ax.relim()
        self.ax.autoscale_view()
        self.ax.figure.canvas.draw_idle()


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
viewer = Viewer()
viewer.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Genius! Thank you so much for taking the time out to help me solve this! It is highly appreciated. I am implementing it into my code now :)